# I want to to create a script to select all nodes at the same edge

Tags: python-3.x, nodes, surface, abaqus

i found how to select all nodes on the surface but i couldn't find how to selsect all nodes at the ame edge

I want to to create a script to select all nodes at the same edge.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.